# Can we always find "relatively unique" embeddings into larger structures?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Given two structures in the same signature $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$, say that $\mathfrak{A}$ is *relatively core in* $\mathfrak{B}$ iff

- $\mathfrak{A}$ is embeddable into $\mathfrak{B}$, and
- any two embeddings $f,g:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$ have $f=g\circ \alpha$ for some automorphism $\alpha\in\mathit{Aut}(\mathfrak{A})$ (in particular, $ran(f)=ran(g)$).

This generalizes the notion of [core structure](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X0970518X) to allow non-rigid examples. In particular, as long as $\mathfrak{A}$ admits no non-surjective self-embeddings, $\mathfrak{A}$ is relatively core in itself.

Interestingly, I don't immediately see a nontrivial obstacle to a structure being relatively core in something else:

> Suppose $\mathfrak{A}$ is an infinite structure with no non-surjective self-embeddings. Must $\mathfrak{A}$ be relatively core in some $\mathfrak{B}\not\cong\mathfrak{A}$ but $\mathfrak{B}\equiv\mathfrak{A}$?

Of course no structure with a non-surjective self-embedding can be relatively core in anything. Meanwhile, the "$\mathfrak{B}\equiv\mathfrak{A}$" condition is required to avoid trivial examples such as $\mathfrak{B}=$ $\mathfrak{A}$ + a "new special point:" by requiring $\mathfrak{B}$ to look reasonably like $\mathfrak{A}$, we give $\mathfrak{A}$ some interesting leverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{A}$ is a nontrivial finite-dimensional $k$-vector space ($k$ an infinite field), then $\mathfrak{A}$ admits no non-surjective self-embeddings, but $\mathfrak{A}$ fails to be relatively core in any elementarily equivalent proper extension $\mathfrak{B}$. Indeed, such a $\mathfrak{B}$ is a $k$-vector space with $\dim(\mathfrak{B})>\dim(\mathfrak{A})$, and $\mathfrak{B}$ admits lots of distinct subspaces of dimension $\dim(\mathfrak{A})$.

This kind of counterexample will generalize to models of classifiable theories (in the Shelah sense) with quantifier elimination in which there are only finitely many dimensions, all of which are finite.

For another kind of example (an unstable one), consider $(\mathbb{Z};<,S)$. This structure admits no nonsurjective self-embeddings, but again it fails to be relatively core in any elementarily equivalent proper extension (since any such structure contains multiple chains isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I've edited to include infiniteness, since that was an accidental omission on my part (are finite structures *really* structures? :P), but the finite-dimensional vector space example answers the question. I'm now very interested in a nontrivial followup ...

Comment: Hm, maybe even the following is nontrivial: which countable models of PA are r.c. in something?

Comment: Almost any question about models of PA is nontrivial to me :0)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I added another example to my answer.